# Okta setting subdomains cookies

Tags: javascript, okta, okta-api

I am using @okta/okta-auth-js and wanting to set multiple domains/subdomains cookies after logging in.

ie. I want to be able to login on app.example.com which will set a cookie for .example.com

However out of the box from the module using authClient.tokenManager.add(token) It looks like it will set it at the domain your script is running.

Does this mean I will need to manually set the cookie myself?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I ended up creating a cookie myself and setting domain with a dot in front of it. Works well and can still use all the sdk's features.